# highlight the current item on the menu dynamically

Tags: php

I am trying to highlight the current page using PHP to select the page.

This is the code I used:

```
<li>
<a href="index.php?pid=4&cat=<?php $d=$cat->id; echo $d ?>" 
    <?php if($cat=$d){echo "class='active'";}?> >
    <?php echo $cat->cat_name ?>
</a>
</li>
```

which the `$d` will give the page id and the `$cat` is the current cat.

Comment: I did if($cat=$d) but not working

Comment: What's the output of `print_r($cat);`?

Comment: As @moose says, you need put double ==, if($cat==$d)

Comment: @MeNa: How would that help? `$cat` is an object, and `$d` would contain an `int` (probably). That comparison is not going to work.

Comment: @Amal: you right too, but yousef must understand the difference between = and ==.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Comparison and assignment

`=` is only for assignment, not for comparison. You need to use `==` for comparison.

### Passing values

Also, you need to pass the current category somehow. One way to do this would be using the URL (e.g.: `www.yourpage.com/script.php?currentCat=5`). You can access this with `$_GET` (e.g. `$_GET['currentCat']`).

### Debugging

Try printing values with `[print_r][1]` (`$d$` and `$cat`). Did you get what you've expected?

### A try

Without knowing your complete code, I can only guess how the exact solution could look like.
A guess would be:

```
<li>
<?php $d=$cat->id;?>
<a href="index.php?pid=4&cat=<?php echo $d; ?>" 
    <?php if($_GET['currentCat']==$d){echo "class='active'";}?>
>
    <?php echo $cat->cat_name; ?>
</a>
</li>
```

I'm not sure about your knowledge of PHP. If you're a beginner, I recommend the [Quakenet Tutorial](http://tut.php-quake.net/en/).

Comment: thanks @moose yes this solved the problem I changed one small thing if($_GET['currentCat']==$d) to if($_GET['cat']==$d) coz I am passing cat on the URL thanks a loot it helped.

Answer (score 1):

An easy and more efficient way is to define each page's name and pass a class to mark the current menu item.

**Example Menu:**

```
<ul>
<li class="<?php if($page=='home'){echo 'current'; } ?>"><a href="">Home</a></li>
<li class="<?php if($page=='contact'){echo 'current'; } ?>"> <a href="">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

*EXPLAINED:*
If a page is loaded and its name equals as defined then apply the `.current` menu class.

Example CSS:

```
li.current a{
background: #f00
}
```

*EXPLAINED:*
Apply the styles for the `.current` menu class in your CSS file.

**Example PHP Page:**

```
<?php
// give each page a unique name e.g. home, contact, about etc.
$page="home";
$class="current";
define($page, $class);
?>
```

*EXPLAINED:*
Each page is defined with a name to compare with the menu list. If a comparison is found the `.current` class is applied.

Using this method is more URL friendly and easy to maintain.